# How to get current view of android screen

Tags: android, video, view

I am developing an Android application which should record a video. There are certain classes that I cannot change due to restrictions of the project, like Preview and VideoRec classes.

Application has one main screen activity and there is a toggle button. Whenever toggle button is checked, video recording should start and vice versa for the unchecked state.

However, VideoRec class' constructor takes a View type parameter for input (VideoRec(View x)). Main activity's screen has a surfaceview and several buttons. What I am trying to do is to just initiate video recording on the same screen, just like the default mediarecorder application of any phone.

My question is; I keep on failing to obtain the View of the screen. I can't use preview or surfaceView types, I get errors saying either classCast Exceptions or invalid preview/surface preview.

Long story short, how can i get the activity's screen as a type of View?

Answer (score 0):

you can provide a public method in your Main Activity which returns the view you need.
Obviously you have to save a reference of that view in your onCreate method activity:

```
 View myView;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.the_layout_id);
      myView = (View)findViewByID(R.id.your_id_view);            
 }


  public View getTheView(){
      return myView;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you have 1 surfaceview where reproducing what you are recording. 
So you must attach your PreviewCallback in the surfaceChanged(...) SurfaceHolder.Callback! After doing this, you'll continue to get preview frame data after a MediaRecorder is running!

For example:

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] _data, Camera _camera) {
                Log.d("onPreviewFrame-surfaceChanged",String.format("Got %d bytes of camera data", _data.length));
            }
        });

}
```

Hope it helps!Cheers